# Mousenter and mouseout event to show border

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following html structure:

```
         <div>
             <p>Name <img src="url" alt="Image A"></p>
             <p>Age <img src="url" alt="Image B"> </p>
             <p><img src="url" alt="Image C"></p>
         </div>
```

When a `mousenter` happens to any element in the html, I want to show a red border only to the element that my mouse is over. The current code that is:

```
       $("*").mouseenter(
                  function(){
                     $(this).css("border","solid red");
        }).mouseleave(
                function(){
                     $(this).css("border","none");
        });
```

However when my mouse enters image A the paragraph that holds image A comes with a border with Image A. I want only Image A to have the border. Can anyone suggest how I can go about  doing this?

Comment: make fiddle for this to have better ans

Comment: When you hover on img, whole <p> tag will have border because it is child of that <p> tag.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: I will do up a fiddle quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QqMQW/)

i think you want this

Hover over the `p` and create borders on `p`

```
 $("div p").mouseenter(

 function () {
     $(this).css("border", "solid red");
 }).mouseleave(

 function () {
     $(this).css("border", "none");
 });
```

Hover over the `image` and create borders on `image`

```
 $("div p img").mouseenter(

 function () {
     $(this).css("border", "solid red");
 }).mouseleave(

 function () {
     $(this).css("border", "none");
 });
```

or you can use `e.stopPropagation();`

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QqMQW/1)

```
$("*").mouseenter(
function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css("border", "solid red");
}).mouseleave(

function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css("border", "none");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QqMQW/1/2)

```
$("*").mouseenter(
function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parents('div').css("border", "none");
    $(this).parents('p').css("border", "none");
    $(this).css("border", "solid red");
}).mouseleave(

function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parents('div').css("border", "none");
    $(this).parents('p').css("border", "none");
    $(this).css("border", "none");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for creating a working demo, but what i am looking for is when user mouseover the the Paragraph, the border is shown to the paragraph and when user mouseovers on the image, the border is only shown to the image. So in your case, it doesn't.

Comment: I think you are helping me to get closer to the solution. When I mouseover to image A, the Paragraph container that holds the image is also bordered red with the image. I only want the image to be bordered red and not the paragraph when the mouse is over the image.

Answer (score 1):

use this

http://jsfiddle.net/bBx2z/

```
$("p:first").mouseenter(
                  function(){
                     $(this).css("border","solid red");
        }).mouseleave(
                function(){
                     $(this).css("border","none");
        });
```

Comment: The same case here. I need every elements to be bordered and not just the paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events will bubble up, meaning they will trigger for the element's parents too. You can stop the bubbling of the event using `stopPropagation()`

```
$("*").mouseenter(
              function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 $(this).css("border","solid red");
    }).mouseleave(
            function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 $(this).css("border","none");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be to add a class that would show the border around the element:

```
$(function(){
  $(elem).on({
    mouseenter:function(){
      $(this).addClass("bordered");
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
      $(this).removeClass("bordered");
    },
  });
})
```

And you CSS:

```
.bordered {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   $("img").mouseenter(
              function(){
                 $(this).css("border","solid red");
    }).mouseleave(
            function(){
                 $(this).css("border","none");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('border');
});
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('border');
```

});

});

css

```
.border{
border-width:3px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#ff9900;
}
```